# Using Rselenium on mac sierra

Tags: r, selenium, web-scraping, phantomjs, rselenium

It seems that every time I update my OS, R, or any browsers `Rselenium` stops working. I can no longer use it with any browser -Firefox, Chrome, or PhantomJS. I've posted my code below.

Session Info:

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Sierra 10.12.2

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] rvest_0.3.2.9000 xml2_1.0.0       RSelenium_1.6.2 

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] httr_1.2.1     magrittr_1.5   R6_2.2.0       tools_3.3.2    curl_2.3       Rcpp_0.12.8   
 [7] jsonlite_1.2   caTools_1.17.1 openssl_0.9.6  bitops_1.0-6   XML_3.98-1.4
```

My work flow is the following:

1. PhantomJS: install in terminal using node npm (install node npm with brew: `brew install node`)

   ```
   npm install -g phantomjs
   phantomjs --version #To check if it installed
       2.1.1  #It did
   ```

   Onto my R session:

   ```
   library(RSelenium) 
   ptm <- phantom() #also tried running checkForServer() and startServer() first but both were deprecated with no substitute stated...
   ```

> [ERROR - 2017-01-06T01:55:35.240Z] GhostDriver - main.fail -
>   {"line":85,"sourceURL":"phantomjs://code/main.js","stack":"global
>   code@phantomjs://code/main.js:85:56"}
>
> phantomjs://platform/console++.js:263 in error

```
    rd <- remoteDriver(browserName = 'phantomjs')
    rd$open()
```

> [1] "Connecting to remote server" Error:   Summary: UnknownError
>   Detail: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the
>   command.       class: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException    Further
>   Details: run errorDetails method

2. Chromedriver: downloaded from https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.27/ and binary file placed in `/usr/local/bin`

   ```
   rd <-remoteDriver(browserName = 'chrome')
   rd$open() #At this point, Google Chrome opens up for 1 second and then closes and an error pops up
   ```

> Selenium message:session not created exception from unknown error:
>   Runtime.evaluate missing 'wasThrown'   (Session info:
>   chrome=55.0.2883.95)   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.23.409710
>   (0c4084804897ac45b5ff65a690ec6583b97225c0),platform=Mac OS X 10.12.2
>   x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace
>   information) Command duration or timeout: 1.09 seconds Build info:
>   version: '3.0.0-beta2', revision: '2aa21c1', time: '2016-08-02
>   15:03:28 -0700' System info: host: 'Cyrus-M.local', ip: '10.0.1.3',
>   os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.12.2',
>   java.version: '1.8.0_101' Driver info:
>   org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
>
> Error:     Summary: SessionNotCreatedException     Detail: A new session
>   could not be created.      class:
>   org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException     Further Details: run
>   errorDetails method

3. Firefox: installed gecko driver in `/usr/local/bin` (without this the following code would produce an error indicating I needed the gecko driver installed)

   ```
   remDr <- remoteDriver$new()
   remDr$open() #a blank Firefox page opens up but then the following error is produced)
   ```

> [1] "Connecting to remote server"
>
> Selenium message:Unsupported Marionette protocol version 2, required 3
>   (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
>   Command duration or timeout: 1.06 seconds Build info: version:
>   '3.0.0-beta2', revision: '2aa21c1', time: '2016-08-02 15:03:28 -0700'
>   System info: host: 'Cyrus-M.local', ip: '10.0.1.3', os.name: 'Mac OS
>   X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.12.2', java.version:
>   '1.8.0_101' Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
>
> Error:     Summary: UnknownError       Detail: An unknown server-side error
>   occurred while processing the command.     class:
>   org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException     Further Details: run
>   errorDetails method

```
    remDr$navigate("http://www.google.com")
```

> Error in checkError(res) :    Undefined error in httr call. httr
>   output: length(url) == 1 is not TRUE

Any help is much appreciated.

**UPDATE**

After upgrading Firefox to the beta version (51.0b11), I can browse successfully but the problems persist using Chrome and PhantomJS.

```
remDr <- remoteDriver$new()
remDr$open()

[1] "Connecting to remote server"
$rotatable
[1] FALSE

$raisesAccessibilityExceptions
[1] FALSE

$appBuildId
[1] "20170103031119"

$version
[1] ""

$platform
[1] "MAC"

$proxy
named list()

$command_id
[1] 1

$nativeEvents
[1] TRUE

$specificationLevel
[1] 0

$acceptSslCerts
[1] FALSE

$processId
[1] 7529

$webdriver.remote.sessionid
[1] "64ac4d92-5761-4865-ba60-9cfaafe92a14"

$browserVersion
[1] "51.0"

$platformVersion
[1] "16.3.0"

$XULappId
[1] "{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}"

$browserName
[1] "firefox"

$takesScreenshot
[1] TRUE

$javascriptEnabled
[1] TRUE

$takesElementScreenshot
[1] TRUE

$platformName
[1] "darwin"

$cssSelectorsEnabled
[1] TRUE

$id
[1] "64ac4d92-5761-4865-ba60-9cfaafe92a14"

remDr$navigate("http://www.google.com") #Firefox opens up and browsing is accessible
```

Comment: I would recommend running a Docker image see http://rpubs.com/johndharrison/RSelenium-Docker . Your chromedriver is showing as 2.23 not 2.27 see https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium/issues/1618 .

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/phantomjs when I used it previously registers phantomjs as a node script see `> more phantomjs` in your terminal. I suspect you will see a node script. This is not pointing to the phantomjs binary. This node package is not official and is actually deprecated.

Comment: @ jdharrison Thanks. Yeah it's odd that it thinks its 2.23. The driver I have is 2.27 (after I downloaded it from the link above). That much be part of the problem. As far as the docker goes, there are instructions for various Linux distributions but not for mac, could I use those instructions on a mac in terminal?

Comment: Running Docker on a Mac is equivalent to either the windows  or linux install. Docker toolbox is equivalent to the windows install as described in the vignette. Docker for Mac is equivalent to the native linux install. Which you use will depend on your resources available. If you have enough ram (as you are running sierra) you should be able to run the more recent Docker for Mac.