# Trying to Webscrape an entire table using R, but only able to get the first line

Tags: r, web-scraping

This is the website I'm trying to scrape from: https://www.premierleague.com/match/38413

I'm trying to get the table that has Match Stats, but when I try to scrape it, I only get the first line, which includes the team names only!

This is the code I'm using:

```R
library(rvest)
url <- "https://www.premierleague.com/match/38413"

my_html <- read_html(url)


tbls_ls <- my_html %>%
  html_nodes("table") %>%
  .[2] %>%
  html_table(fill = TRUE)
```

I'm no R expert so I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong, but would love assistance!

Comment: The problem is the table "Match Stats" is generated by `JavaScript`, i.e. `rvest` by itself is not able to scrape it. You need other tools, e.g. `RSelenium` (slow, very slow and not very stable), `PhantomJS` or `V8`.

Comment: Most likely the data  isn't actually in the page. Instead the page is loaded, and Javscript code  then fetches the data and injects it into the page within the browser. The R page functions (as in rvest)  only do the http GET for the page - they don't run any scripts in the page.

Comment: Mmk, would I be able to acquire the information by going through the page source? By inspecting the page i‘ve been able to find all the information i need, but i dont know how to collect it all.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41496552/extracting-html-table-from-a-website-in-r (it's the same website at least)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to extract the match stats with the following script :

```
library(RSelenium)
library(XML)
library(RCurl)
shell('docker run -d -p 4445:4444 selenium/standalone-firefox')
remDr <- remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "localhost", port = 4445L, browserName = "firefox")
remDr$open()
remDr$navigate('https://www.premierleague.com/match/38413')
remDr$screenshot(display = TRUE, useViewer = TRUE) 

# Close accept cookie
obj_Accept_Cookie <- remDr$findElement("xpath", "/html/body/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div[5]/button[1]")
obj_Accept_Cookie$clickElement()

remDr$executeScript("scroll(0, 5000)")
remDr$executeScript("scroll(0, 15000)")

obj_Table_Stats <- remDr$findElement("xpath", "//*[@id='mainContent']/div/section[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/ul/li[3]")
obj_Table_Stats$clickElement()
remDr$screenshot(display = TRUE, useViewer = TRUE) 

page_Content <- remDr$getPageSource()[[1]]
table <- readHTMLTable(page_Content)[[3]]
table
```